# Remove string from multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to remove the `0` from columns with cell `↑ 0`, and result into `↑`. Such that

```
   Data myda   xda
0   ↑ *  ↑ 0     0
1     *    *   100
2  ↑ **  ↑ 0  0.05
```

into

```
   Data myda   xda
0   ↑ *  ↑       0
1     *    *   100
2  ↑ **  ↑    0.05
```

The code is realised

```
import pandas as pd


pat = r'^?(0)$'
df = pd.DataFrame ( {'Data': ['↑ *', '*', '↑ **'],
                     'myda': ['↑ 0', '*', '↑ 0'],
                     'xda': ['0', '100', '0.05']} )
df=df.replace(dict(string={pat: ''}), regex=True)
```

But,this does not return the expected output

Comment: ``df.myda = df.myda.str.rstrip('0')`` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Extension to @sammy suggestion, applying this to all column can be achieved using `lambda`

```
df = pd.DataFrame ( {'Data': ['↑ *', '*', '↑ **'],
                     'myda': ['↑ 0', '*', '↑ 0'],
                     'xda': ['0', '100', '0.05']} )

df[df.columns] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('0'))
```

Output

```
   Data myda   xda
0   ↑ *   ↑       
1     *    *     1
2  ↑ **   ↑   0.05
```